# Is is possible to choose internal IP for kubernetes host network pod

Tags: kubernetes

My kubernetes node has two internal IPs

```
status:
  addresses:
  - address: 10.10.96.70
    type: ExternalIP
  - address: 10.10.97.77
    type: InternalIP
  - address: 10.10.96.70
    type: InternalIP
```

When I deploy a hostnetwork pod, the first internal IP (10.10.97.77) is always used. Is it possible to use the second internal IP instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can override on your kubelet with the `--node-ip string` option.

```
--node-ip string
IP address of the node. If set, kubelet will use this IP address for the node
```

More information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)

Comment: Doesn't work as I specify --node-ip 10.10.96.70, then k8s with vsphere cloud provider will pull 10.10.97.77 into the list.

Comment: Well it will always pull all the interfaces on your machine. But which one do you want as your main IP?

Comment: 10.10.96.70 is my main IP

Comment: did you check that `10.10.96.70` is where your traffic is going through?